# .Net Regular Expression to get text between square-bracket tags

Tags: regex, vb.net

Alright so I want to grab the information on a website thats between

[usernames] and [/usernames]

I know how to get the string but how would I use regex to only have the information in the middle.

Remember I am going to be having more then one thing on the page.

Comment: I can't tell whether or not you know this, so I'll ask: are you aware that VB.NET does not have regular expressions? It's the .NET Framework that has regular expressions.

Comment: @John: We still need to know which language the OP is using in order to craft the most useful answers; **VB.NET regex** is a nice, concise way to supply both bits of information.

Comment: @Alan: the consensus on meta is to keep the language tag in the tags, and out of the title. An answer about ".NET Regular Expression" should also be useful to C# or F# developers, assuming they can read enough VB.NET. C# and F# developers might ignore a question about "VB.NET Regular Expressions".

Comment: @Alan: a title like that also reinforces the false impression that features like regular expressions belong to the languages and not to the Framework. Let's call things what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    'Sample input
    Dim html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head>" & vbNewLine & "<body><p>[usernames]Your Name Here[/usernames]</p>[usernames]Another Name Here[/usernames]</body></html>"
    'Named pattern
    Dim p = "\[usernames\](?<UserNames>.*?)\[/usernames\]"
    'Grab all of the matches
    Dim Matches = Regex.Matches(html, p, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
    'Make sure we found something
    If Matches IsNot Nothing AndAlso Matches.Count > 0 Then
        'Loop through all of the matches
        For Each Match As Match In Matches
            'Make sure our sub-group was a success
            If Match.Groups("UserNames").Success Then
                Trace.WriteLine(Match.Groups("UserNames").Value)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off parsing the document for every instance.

regex to match one instance would be

```
/<usernames>([^<]+?)<\/usernames>/
```